# Facebook Pixel - Multi Tenant ecommerce site

Tags: facebook, facebook-pixel, facebook-ads

I have a multi tenant application - [www.example-app.com](http://www.example-app.com). When I onboard a new client, they get a URL suffix ([www.example-app.com/client1](http://www.example-app.com/client1), [www.example-app.com/client2](http://www.example-app.com/client2) ... and so on).

Several clients have asked to have their pixel setup on the site. It looks like facebook requires "domain verification" and the clients don't own the domain (I do). When we had just a single client, we allowed them to verify our domain for their ad account but now that we have more than one client, we are looking to send data to different pixel id's based on the client.

How is the best way to setup pixel tracking so that it feeds back to their individual ad accounts and still allows them to run ads based on the data?

Do they need to verify their own domain ([www.client1.com](http://www.client1.com), [www.client2.com](http://www.client2.com), and so on) and then we load up an ajax call to something like "pixel.client1.com?...whateverparams..." to have the pixel code run so that they can have the data come in on a verified domain?

Comment: Is the domain verification part mandatory? https://www.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755?id=1205376682832142 - point 5.) there suggests they should be able to proceed with the "I don't have a website" option, and create their pixel ID. (Not sure if it will _work_ on your site then though.)

Comment: Yea, I think it is if they want to run ads pushing them to a landing page when they click the “ad link” … which the landing page is on my domain